# Custom Listview inside an AlertDialog hides dialog's message?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am working on an application in which I have a list populated in an `AlertDialog`. On some event the dialog appears, showing its `Title`, `Message` and the `Custom listview`. Problem is, when I add more than 4 entries in the list, the Dialog's message that is set gets hidden by the list view. I want to show list view below the message, no matter how long the list is. Can any one help me out????

Implementation is as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(xActivity.this);
     builder.setTitle("Title");
     builder.setMessage("Following items are in the List");                 
     final ListView modeList = new ListView(xActivity.this);
     ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(xActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, simpleArray);
     modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
     modeList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
     builder.setView(modeList);
     builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

    // Do Something

    }
}});

final Dialog dialog = builder.create(); 
dialog.show();
```

Any help is appreciated.... :-)

Comment: Alert dialog has a specific length. If the length of the list exceeds to a specific amount, it will overtake the message. one good way to solve it is to create dialog like activity.

Comment: With the standard AlertDialog you can only have one of message or list but not both, you should go with a custom dialog or a custom view for your alert dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest and think there the best way is to create your custom dialog instead of the predefined AlertDialog. Create your own xml.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Following items are in the List"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.15" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_listview);

Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }    
});

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the same manner exposed above, **only** that instead of using basic `Dialog` class, the [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) class which is keeps its state when the device's state changes (rotation/keyboard...)
Hope it helps... ;)